# Show Table DATA in one Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i have some table with users and they all link to a journey 
so instead of show a Select of the journey where each user is in a row of their own i want to Select the users to be in one row

I can show all the information in a select with this code, but dont no how to make it in one row.

```
CREATE TABLE Journeys (
    `Journeypk` INT,
    `mempickuppoint` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `memdropoffpoint` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `dteestimatedarrival` DATETIME,
    `strreceivedby` VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO Journeys VALUES
    (1,'london','berlin','2019-08-17 00:00:00','jay');

CREATE TABLE Journeypassengers (
    `passengerpk` INT,
    `Journeyfk` INT,
    `contactfk` INT
);
INSERT INTO Journeypassengers VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (3,1,3);

CREATE TABLE Contacts (
    `Contactpk` INT,
    `name` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `strreference` INT
);
INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES
    (1,'sam',12412),
    (2,'mark',7854674),
    (3,'chloe',568345);

CREATE TABLE Vulnerbilityflags (
    `Vulnerbilityflagspk` INT,
    `strflag` VARCHAR(39) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `contactfk` INT
);
INSERT INTO Vulnerbilityflags VALUES
    (1,'DO NOT VISIT ALONE',2),
    (2,'Female Only',2),
    (3,'Learning Disabilities',1),
    (4,'Male Only',3),
    (5,'Physical Disabilities',1),
    (6,'Serious long term or terminally illness',3),
    (7,'Male Only',1);

CREATE TABLE Tenant (
    `Tenantpk` INT,
    `strstatus` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `contactfk` INT
);
INSERT INTO Tenant VALUES
    (1,'Active',1),
    (2,'Active',2),
    (3,'Active',3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tenancy (
    `Tenancypk` INT,
    `address` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `DtePlannedarrival` DATETIME,
    `dteRealarrival` VARCHAR(19) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `dtePlannedDepartureDate` VARCHAR(19) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `dteRealDepartureDate` VARCHAR(19) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `tenantfk` INT
);
INSERT INTO Tenancy VALUES
    (1,'433 york road en57 7wj','2019-08-01 00:00:00','2019-08-01 00:00:00','2019-08-16 00:00:00','NULL',1),
    (2,'656 south street hg70 9qb','2019-08-01 00:00:00','2019-08-02 00:00:00','2019-08-16 00:00:00','NULL',2),
    (3,'6 mill road n9 6fg','2019-08-17 00:00:00','NULL','NULL','NULL',1),
    (4,'85 kings road nw2 1re','2019-08-17 00:00:00','NULL','NULL','NULL',2),
    (5,'9 grange road rg24 5aa','2019-08-17 00:00:00','NULL','NULL','NULL',3),
    (6,'7 fake street rg15 5aa','2019-07-01 00:00:00','2019-07-02 00:00:00','2019-07-30 00:00:00','2019-07-31 00:00:00',1);
```

```
Select Journeys.Journeypk,
       Journeys.mempickuppoint,
       Journeys.memdropoffpoint,
       Journeys.dteestimatedarrival,
       Journeys.strreceivedby,
       contacts.name,
       tenant.strstatus,
       tenancy.dtePlannedDepartureDate,
       contacts.strreference,
       V1.strflag,
       V2.strflag,
       V3.strflag,
       V4.strflag,
       V5.strflag,
       V6.strflag
from journeys
left join Journeypassengers on Journeypassengers.journeyfk = journeys.journeypk
left join contacts on contacts.contactpk = Journeypassengers.contactfk
left join tenant on tenant.contactfk = contacts.contactpk
left join tenancy on tenancy.tenantfk = tenant.tenantpk and tenancy.strstatus = 'Active'
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v1 on V1.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v1.strflag = 'DO NOT VISIT ALONE' 
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v2 on v2.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v2.strflag = 'Female Only'
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v3 on v3.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v3.strflag = 'Learning Disabilities'
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v4 on v4.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v4.strflag = 'Male Only'
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v5 on v5.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v5.strflag = 'Physical Disabilities'
left join Vulnerbilityflags as v6 on v6.contactfk = contacts.contactpk and v6.strflag = 'Serious long term or terminally illness'
```

Output to be like this

```
    JourneyPK   memPickUpPoint  memDropOffPoint dteEstimatedArrival strReceivedBy   SU1 strStatus   dtePlannedDepartureDate SU1 Nass    SU1 V   SU1 V1  SU1 V2  SU1 V3  SU1 V4  SU1 V5  SU2 strStatus   dtePlannedDepartureDate SU2 NASS    SU2 V   SU2 V1  SU2 V2  SU2 V3  SU2 V4  SU2 V5  SU3 strStatus   dtePlannedDepartureDate SU3 NASS    SU3 V   SU3 V1  SU3 V2  SU3 V3  SU3 V4  SU3 V5
1   london  berlin  17/08/2019  jay sam active  16/08/2019  12412           Learning Disabilities   Male Only   Physical Disabilities       mark    active  16/08/2019  7854674     Female Only                 chloe   active      568345              Male Only       Serious long term or terminally illness
```

Comment: Simplify your problem. [mcve]

Comment: "_I can show all the information in a select with this code, but dont no how to make it in one row._" Why not? What does that `select` return? Why is that wrong?

Comment: @jarlh I have this is the 4th time i have  rewritten this

Comment: @underscore_d it shows all the data in many rows if you got to SQL Fiddle and use the TABLE in put and code it will show you

Comment: We shouldn't have to do that to understand the question though, as the Help Centre states; it should be in the question itself.

Comment: @underscore_d do u really want to see what it currently shows will that give u a index or what to do to help me or me giving the tool to get to that dosent help at all. i have posted this up 4 difffernt time showing everything and i have been getting comments to do this do that or to much code to read this is the simplest way to show people the code im doing on the tables i have to get the outcome that i want, but if showing you the table that the code get atm then i shall email it to you or PM if u can do that or even post here in the comment but im telling u now it wont look all pretty

Comment: or go to this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e8879/8 to see the outcome and also test

Comment: Tag correctly. This is obviously NOT sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pivot and unpivot statements. 
The select would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
            SELECT Journeypk,
                    mempickuppoint,
                    memdropoffpoint,
                    dteestimatedarrival,
                    strreceivedby,
                    det,
                    CAST(rn AS NVARCHAR(3)) + '_' + COL AS rr
            FROM   (
                        SELECT Journeys.Journeypk,
                                Journeys.mempickuppoint,
                                Journeys.memdropoffpoint,
                                Journeys.dteestimatedarrival,
                                Journeys.strreceivedby,
                                CAST(contacts.name AS NVARCHAR(100)) NAME,
                                CAST(tenant.strstatus AS NVARCHAR(100)) strstatus,
                                CAST(tenancy.dtePlannedDepartureDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) dtePlannedDepartureDate,
                                CAST(contacts.strreference AS NVARCHAR(100)) strreference,
                                CAST(Vulnerbilityflags.strflag AS NVARCHAR(100)) strflag,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY journeys.Journeypk) AS rn
                        FROM   journeys
                                LEFT JOIN Journeypassengers
                                    ON  Journeypassengers.journeyfk = journeys.journeypk
                                LEFT JOIN contacts
                                    ON  contacts.contactpk = Journeypassengers.contactfk
                                LEFT JOIN tenant
                                    ON  tenant.contactfk = contacts.contactpk
                                LEFT JOIN tenancy
                                    ON  tenancy.tenantfk = tenant.tenantpk
                                LEFT JOIN Vulnerbilityflags
                                    ON  Vulnerbilityflags.contactfk = contacts.contactpk
                    ) AS t
                    UNPIVOT(
                        DET FOR COL IN (NAME, strstatus, dtePlannedDepartureDate, strreference, strflag)
                    ) AS h
        ) AS ttt
        PIVOT(
            MAX(det) FOR rr IN ([1_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [1_NAME], [1_strflag], [1_strreference], [1_strstatus], 
                                [2_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [2_NAME], [2_strflag], [2_strreference], [2_strstatus], 
                                [3_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [3_NAME], [3_strflag], [3_strreference], [3_strstatus], 
                                [4_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [4_NAME], [4_strflag], [4_strreference], [4_strstatus], 
                                [5_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [5_NAME], [5_strflag], [5_strreference], [5_strstatus], 
                                [6_dtePlannedDepartureDate], [6_NAME], [6_strflag], [6_strreference], [6_strstatus])
        ) AS pvt
```

Comment: The type of column "strreference" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: The CAST in the subquery should help

Comment: Thank you this way works very well, i have made some changes to fit what i need but you have done it